# Any scrolling calendar that can start with the current date?

Tags: android, calendar

I tried [SingleRowCalendar](https://github.com/miso01/SingleRowCalendar) and [Horizontal Calendar Sample](https://github.com/B-Sahana/Horizontal-Calendar-Sample) but I was unsuccessful because jcenter() is obsolete...

[ScrollDatePicker](https://github.com/GastricSpark/ScrollDatePicker) works fine, but I searched and couldn't find how to set the current default date when opening the app...

Any solution?

Comment: ScrollDatePicker seems to have a function to have a function `setStartDate` isn't it possible to use that?

Comment: isn't this just asking for a library ? so the question will get closed as off-topic ?

Comment: @JustSightseeing **setStartDate** only defines the beginning of the calendar with "2020-12-12", but not the current date which is today